# How to do preallocation in storing field variables in matlab

Tags: matlab, field-names, pre-allocation

I am storing the field variables calculated in a for loop in a vector by appending the values, However I would like to preallocate first for performance. I tried to vectorize this operation but it does not give me what I would like to accomplish. I have put the example of the operation below. How do I do the preallocation in this? For speed.

```
j=('load raw.mat');
var=fields(j);
val_mat=[];
kk=fieldnames(j);
for i=(length(kk)-Var_no)+1:Var_no+(length(kk)-Var_no)
val_mat=[val_mat j.(var{i})];
end
```

Comment: I am confused. This isn't even valid code. Are you just trying to create an array of all field values in a struct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your code it looks like you are trying to grab all variables stored in `raw.mat` and concatenate them. To do this, you can replace the loop with `struct2cell` to convert all field values to a cell array of values and then use `cat` to concatenate them

```
data = load('raw.mat');
values = struct2cell(data);
val_mat = cat(2, values{:});
```

Since we have removed the loop, there is no need to pre-allocate.

I've also taken the liberty to rewrite your code as valid MATLAB code.